# Django distinct with order by different column

Tags: django, postgresql

I have such model

```
    class Product(models.Model):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        cell = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Now I need a queryset that must be ordered by creation date and unique cell, something like `Product.objects.order_by('created_at').distinct('cell')` but I got an sql error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("apps_product"."cell")
```

How should queryset be changed to get required result?

Comment: Can you share your SQL error?

Comment: maybe with objectS instead of object in Product.object.order_by('created_at').distinct('cell')

Comment: @JureC. - django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("apps_product"."cell")

Answer (score 2):

Folowing your error message, you should try:

`Product.objects.order_by('cell', '-created_at').distinct('cell')`

Comment: like this you'll end up with a queryset that's sorted on `cell`, whereas the question requests a queryset sorted by `-created_at`. I think this not possible in combination with `distinct()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible without a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). There is an open [feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24218) that would allow queries like:

```py
qs = (
  Product.objects
  # deduplicate on "cell", keeping the most recently created record
  .order_by("cell", "-created_at").distinct("cell")
  # then order the result of the distinct subquery to get most recently created first
  .order_by("-created_at")
)
```

If you try this query now (as of Django 4.1.7), it will fail with the same error message you posted.

As a comment under the feature requests explains, you can try something like:

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery
distinct = (
  Product.objects
  # deduplicate on "cell", keeping the most recently created record
  .order_by("cell", "-created_at").distinct("cell")
  .values("pk")
)
qs = (
  Product.objects
  .filter(pk__in=Subquery(distinct))
  # then order the result of the distinct subquery to get most recently created first
  .order_by("-created_at")
)
```